# Is it possible to programmatically simulate 3d mouse on mac?

Tags: macos, blender

I would like to simulate 3D mouse operation to rotate/pan/zoom elements in "Blender" (on OSX).
Is it possible?

Thanks a tone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Mouse Button Emulation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Keyboard_and_Mouse#Mouse_Button_Emulation)

Under File -> User Preferences -> Input, tick 'Emulate 3 Button Mouse'. The link shows the default shortcuts for an Apple one button mouse.

Answer (score 0):

did you get to solve your problem? We're trying to rotate an Object via Java in another 3D App (3DVia). Since we couldn't find an API, we want to simulate a Space-Mouse. We tried the Java Robot class, but you can only move the primary mouse cursor.